# Posting drop down menu value to mysql cell

Tags: php, mysql, post

Alrighty, so i'm quite a beginner when it comes to PHP and MySQL programming so the problem might be quite noobish but anyway here's my situation. I've got a content page with a dropdown menu that should give me a $_POST value (the options are taken from a database column): here's the code for that

```
    <link href="../css/pagestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php
include("../panel/config.php");

    $db = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { //if connection database fails
     echo("Connection not established " .
     mysqli_connect_error($db) . "</p>");
       }  

    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = '1' ORDER BY username ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

    if (!$result) { 
     echo("Error, the query could not be executed: " .
     mysqli_error($db) . "</p>");
     mysqli_close($db);
     }

    echo "
  <form action='myscript' method='post'>
   <select name='test'>
        <option value = 'none' selected = 'selected' >
          `Select a DJ:` </option>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo '<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">' . $row['username']. '</option>';
       }
     echo"     
     <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
     </select>
    </form> ";
    ?>
```

Quite a bit of code for such a small function i know. Anyway the drop down menu gets its options from a database column and that works fine, now when i press the submit button, it runs another php page that's coded like this:

```
<link href="../css/pagestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><html>
<?php 
include("../panel/config.php");

$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$id = $_POST['test'];

$order = "UPDATE  `habboxli_system`.`users` SET  `points` = points+1 WHERE  `users`.`username` ='$id'";
mysql_query($order);

echo "name is $id";

mysqli_close($con);
echo "Vote posted!";
?>
```

This code should take the value that was chosen in the drop down menu and use it to update a specific cell in the database, i signed it to a variable called $id just for testing purposes but the value seems to be blank, so from that i presume that the drop down menu didn't return a value when it navigated from the original page (www.mywebsite.com/#/option.php) to the myscript.php page (www.mywebsite.com/#/myscript.php). Any help on how to get this to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are querying with mysql_query, but you are using mysqli. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Does "name is $id" output "name is something" or does it output "name is Vote posted!"

Comment: Check the `action` attribute: `<form action='myscript' method='post'>`. Should it be `action='myscript.php'`? And, take a look at the php manual for parameterizing and writing correct queries with `mysqli`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @Tom the output was "name is Vote posted!"

Comment: Also the action attribute doesn't work if it's myscript.php. Both of the files are meant to be content pages, so they're both in a ../pages/ folder. The myscript.php page only loads up if the action is 'myscript'.

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments, you are using the mysql_query function mixed in with the mysqli functions.

I got the code to work for me by changing

```
mysql_query($order);
```

To:

```
mysqli_query($con, $order);
```

You can also debug what was passed to the script by simply printing the $_POST array:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: The problem isn't passing it to the database. I can get that to work by using a username in the query, it's getting the drop-down menu value to be that specific username is what it doesn't do. The post method doesn't work and i think it's because the submit button refreshes the page. (Something that's important is that the 2 files are in a content block so they're both in the .../pages/ folder and when the submit button is clicked, i'm thinking it shouldn't refresh the page but rather just switch to the other page with the name (aka the drop-down menu value) parameter passed along.)

Comment: You need to look into AJAX if you do not want the page to refresh. A POST WILL send the form data to a new page/script. PHP is a server side language so the data has to get passed to the server. If you are attempting to update another content block in real time then you need a CLIENT side language javascript/jQuery/etc.